# Помогите с выводом страницы успешной отправки

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, email

Нужно сделать так, чтобы после отправки данных с формы выводилась страница успешной отправки или модальное окно с успешной отправкой.

Я уже всё пробовал подставлять, итог один - Выводится `<p>` Заявка отправлена `</p>` В указанном месте.

Как это можно реализовать, чтобы я понял, где ошибка допущена. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
<?php
    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

    if($post)
    {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
        $tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
        $error = '';
        if(!$name)
        {
            $error .= 'Пожалуйста введите ваше имя<br />';
        }

        // Проверка телефона
        function ValidateTel($valueTel)
        {
            $regexTel = "/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9] 
{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/";
            if($valueTel == "") {
                return false;
            } else {
                $string = preg_replace($regexTel, "", $valueTel);
            }
                return empty($string) ? true : false;
            }
            if(!$email)
            {
                $error .= "Пожалуйста введите email<br />";
            }
            if($email && !ValidateTel($email))
            {
                $error .= "Введите корректный email<br />";
            }
            if(!$error)
                // (length)
                if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1)
                {
                    $error .= "Введите ваше сообщение<br />";
                }
                if(!$error)
                {
                    $name_tema = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($name) ."?=";

                    $subject ="Новая заявка на обратную связь с сайта katiebeflower.pl";
                    $subject1 = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($subject) ."?=";
                    /*
                      $message ="\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\nИмя: " .$name."\n\nТелефон: ".$tel."\n\n";
                    */
                    $message1 ="\n\nИмя: ".$name."\n\nТелефон: " .$tel."\n\nE-mail: " .$email."\n\nСообщение: 
 ".$message."\n\n"; 


                    $header = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";

                    $header .= "From: Новая заявка на обратную связь <manager@gmail.com>\n\n";  
                    $mail = mail("test@gmail.com", $subject1, iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $message1), iconv ('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $header));

                    if($mail)
                    {
                        echo 'OK';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
                }
            }
            ?>
JS:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".form-cont").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "assets/php/contact.php",
          data: str,
          success: function(msg) {
              if(msg == 'OK') {
                  result = '<p>Заявка отправлена</p>';
                  $(".fields").hide();
              } else {
                  result = msg;
              }
              $('.note').html(result);
         }
       });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас идет вывод значения переменной result в class note.
Если хотите, чтобы переводило на другую страницу замените JS так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".form-cont").submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "assets/php/contact.php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          document.location.href = "https://site.ru";
        } else {
          result = msg;
        }
        $('.note').html(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```